# Finding addresses of structs with different instances

Tags: c, struct, memory-address

Studying for an exam and I came across an interesting question.

I have a struct:

```
struct vehicle {
long carId;
short wheels:3;
short fuelTank : 6;
short weight;
} x[5][5];
```

and the address of x is 0xaaa and memory is aligned at multiples of 4 what would be the address of x[1]?

I have no idea where to start but I found the size of the struct which is 16, and the size of struct when x[5][5] is 400 which is obviously a multiple of 16. 
One of these is the answer:

```
a) 0xD2 b) 0xEA c)0xDC d) 0xAB
```

but i can not know how to get from 0xaaa to one of these.

Comment: How did you reach the conclusion that the size of the struct is 16?

Comment: @Cristik using (sizeof(x))

Comment: OK, but that will give you the size of the struct using the memory alignment that corresponds to your machine, which is not necessarily the same as the value from the exam question. You will need to take into consideration that when you compute the size of the struct.

Comment: Given that 0xAAA is not aligned on a multiple of 4 bytes, I'm left puzzling about how you can provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is written in the question that "...memory is aligned at multiples of 4" it is supposed that type long occupies 4 bytes.

Two adjacent bit fields

```
short wheels:3;
short fuelTank : 6;
```

can be accomodate in one object of type `short int` . So they occupy two bytes (though in general case it is implementation defined) the same way as the next data member

```
short weight;
```

Thus we get the size of the structure is equal to 8 bytes.

`x[1]` is second element of the array and has type `struct vechicle[5]`
So as the size of the structure is equal to 8 then the size of the element of the array is equal to `8 * 5 = 40`. In the hexadecimal notation it is equal to `0x28`

Thus the address of the second element of the array that is of `x[1]` is

```
0xaaa
+
 0x28 
=====
0xad2
```

Comment: Beautiful, Thank you for the well explained and quick response!